# What are the requirements for type T in this case?

Tags: c++11, stdvector

Given the following function:

```
template<class T, typename Iterator, typename Function >
T map_reduce(Iterator start, Iterator end, Function f) {
   std::Vector<T> vec;
   for(; start != end; ++start){
     vec.push_back(f(*start)); 
   }
   return *start;
}
```

Can someone explain me why the type `T` must in this case `operator=` and `Constructor missing parameters` and `copy c'tor` ?

I think that `T` must `copy c'tor` because the function return it by-value. But I don't have idea why `T` must also `constructor missing parameters` and `operator=`.

Comment: I assume you mean `std::vector<T>`. C++ is case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back):

> ```
> void push_back( const T& value ); (1)
> void push_back( T&& value ); (2)
> ```
>
> Type requirements
>
> - T must meet the requirements of [*CopyInsertable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CopyInsertable) in order to use overload (1).
> - T must meet the requirements of [*MoveInsertable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/MoveInsertable) in order to use overload (2).

Which of these is selected depends on the type of `f`. Let's assume that `f` returns an lvalue-reference, which matches (1), because that's the more restrictive one.

That requires, given

```
std::allocator<T> m;
T* p;
```

the expression

```
std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<T>>::construct(m, p, f(*start));
```

to be well-formed. The note helpfully informs us, in this case, that will be

```
::new((void*)p) T(f(*start))
```

You are also (copy?) constructing a `T` in the return value, when you `return *start;`. This is likely the source of your "constructor missing parameters" error, as I would expect `*start` to only relate to `T` via `f`.

Note that this is rather likely to be undefined behaviour, as you have just incremented `start` until it is equal to `end`. Someone trying to `map_reduce` everything in a container will pass a non-dereferenceable iterator as `end`.

As for the missing `operator=`, who knows? You haven't provided any context to the types involved in the instantiation of this error.